# Carbon Date how to create date using string date and user language

Tags: php, date

how to create date using string date and user language

```
function createDate(string $date , string $culture) 
{   
    Carbon::setLocale( $culture);      
    $datetime = Carbon::create($datetime );      
    return $date ->isoformat('L'); 
}
```

if current user in english work well
but if current user in french not working

```
$datetime='12/20/2022 10:20:20 ';  $culture ="en" // en format MM/DD/YYYY =====\> OK

$datetime='20/12/2022 10:20:20 '; $culture ="Fr"  // Fr format DD/MM/YYYY ======\>Exception
```

Comment: European format is detected as `d-m-Y`, not `d/m/Y`. You might have better luck specifying a format based on `$culture`, then using `createFromFormat`

Comment: SCOPE!?!?! Where does `$datetime` come from

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a format for each input type (language) in an array and then use Carbon::createFromFormat.

```
function createFromInput(string $input, string $lang){
  $inputFormat = ['en' => 'm/d/Y H:i:s', 'fr' => 'd/m/Y H:i:s', 'de' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s'];
  return Carbon::createFromFormat($inputFormat[$lang],$input);
}
```

Examples for using the function:

```
$lang = 'en';
$input = '12/20/2022 10:20:20';
echo createFromInput($input, $lang);
//2022-12-20 10:20:20

$lang = 'fr';
$input = '20/12/2022 10:20:20';
echo createFromInput($input, $lang);
//2022-12-20 10:20:20
```

Variant for DateTime:

```
function createFromInput(string $input, string $lang){
  $inputFormat = ['en' => 'm/d/Y H:i:s', 'fr' => 'd/m/Y H:i:s', 'de' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s'];
  return DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat[$lang],$input);
}

$lang = 'en';
$input = '12/20/2022 10:20:20';
echo createFromInput($input, $lang)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2022-12-20 10:20:20

$lang = 'fr';
$input = '20/12/2022 10:20:20';
echo createFromInput($input, $lang)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2022-12-20 10:20:20
```

To try on https://3v4l.org/Q3hoA

Comment: thanks for replay but I don't know wich format date entry by user [ 'm/d/Y H:i:s' ,'m/d/Y H:i:','m/d/Y' , 'd/m/Y H:i:s','d/m/Y H:i','d/m/Y ' ,....] but we carbon in carbon a function   $date = Carbon::createFromLocaleIsoFormat('!L LTS', $culture , $datetime )->locale($culture);